# disable-output-escaping not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some XML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<unclear reason="illegible"/> elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris <unclear reason="illegible"/> ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
<unclear reason="illegible"/> non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

When I try and run

```
<xsl:value-of select="/p" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

it doesn't return the xml tags. How can I include the tags in value-of query?

hat I would like it to include the whole text with something to identify the unclear tags in the text.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, the `value-of` an element is, by definition, the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.  You can't "include the tags in value-of query" but you could use `copy-of` instead of `value-of` to copy the whole `p` element to the output, including its children (text nodes and elements)

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/p" />
```

or if you want the content of the `p` element but not the surrounding `<p>` and `</p>` tags (e.g. if you're inserting the content into another element) then

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/p/node()" />
```

---

If you want to convert the `unclear` elements to something else rather than including them as-is then you probably want to use an *identity template* based transformation instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- copy everything from input to output verbatim, except where
       a more specific template applies -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- handle unclear elements differently -->
  <xsl:template match="unclear">
    <xsl:text>__UNCLEAR__</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your sample input this would produce

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,__UNCLEAR__ elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris __UNCLEAR__ ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
__UNCLEAR__ non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can change the unclear tags to be included in the output? I ran copy-of and it returns only the xml tags. What I would like it to include the whole text with something to identify the unclear tags in the text.

Comment: @user2075215 what do you mean "included in the output"?  If you use `copy-of` instead of `value-of` it should do what you need.